# How to checked child checkbox dynamically if I checked Parent checkbox in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have one parent checkbox and one child checkbox in App.js Now If I checked Parent checkbox and all Child checkbox have to checked how to achieve this using statefull component in react

This is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Checkbox from "./Checkbox/Checkbox";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      checked: false
    }
  }

checkbox = () => {
  if(this.state.checked === false) {
    this.setState({
      checked: this.state.true
    })
  } else {
    this.setState({
      checked: this.state.false
    })
  }
}


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input checked={this.state.checked} onChange={() => this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })} type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" />
            <div>
              <h1>Child checkbox</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
              <Checkbox onChange={this.checkbox}></Checkbox>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should pass down checkox state to
Checkbox component as prop.

```
<Checkbox checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.checkbox} /> and then in Checkbox component should apply logic based on checked prop.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the `toggleCheckbox` function to change the state of the checkbox.

Secondly, It's bad practice to call setState in the render method.

and lastly, you can pass the state of the checkbox to the child component through props.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Checkbox from "./Checkbox/Checkbox";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      checked: false
    }
  }

toggleCheckbox = () => {
  this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input checked={this.state.checked} onChange={() => this.toggleCheckbox} type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" />
            <div>
              <h1>Child checkbox</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
              <Checkbox checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.toggleCheckbox}></Checkbox>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```